# JTable keeps sorting numbers as Strings

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I want to sort the table correctly comparing the correct classes, not strings.
I'm using a TableRowSorter:

```
TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter<CustomModelTable>(modelData);
tablaEJ.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

I overrided the method getColumnClass in CustomModelTable so I get the correct class depending on the column's name (this was made because types are defined programatically):

```
@Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
    {
        try {
            if (columnIndex < this.getColumnCount()) {
                String name = getColumnName(columnIndex); //This just gets the header of the column
                name = name.toLowerCase();
                switch (name) {
                    case "int":
                    case "int[]":
                    case "núm.":
                    case "int[][]": return Integer.class; //Or Class.forName("java.lang.Integer");
                    case "byte":
                    case "byte[]":
                    case "byte[][]": return Class.forName("java.lang.Byte");
                    case "long":
                    case "long[]":
                    case "long[][]": return Class.forName("java.lang.Long");
                    case "float":
                    case "float[]":
                    case "float[][]": return Class.forName("java.lang.Float");
                    case "double":
                    case "double[]":
                    case "double[][]": return Class.forName("java.lang.Double");
                    case "boolean":
                    case "boolean[]":
                    case "boolean[][]": return Class.forName("java.lang.Boolean");
                    case "char":
                    case "char[]":
                    case "char[][]": return Class.forName("java.lang.Character");
                    case "string":
                    case "string[]":
                    case "string[][]": return Class.forName("java.lang.String");
                    default: return Class.forName("java.lang.String");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here's an screenshot:
[Table wrongly sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcnFk.png)

The most curious thing is that I print the types:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tablaEJ.getModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
     System.out.println(tablaEJ.getModel().getColumnClass(i));
}
```

And it returns the expected output (print of the above table):

```
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Integer
```

Honestly, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry but nothing no title, no whole post saying what you want to achieve. Please provide this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "safe" way is to declare which column indices are numbers:

```
public static class CustomTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
        private final List<Integer> columnIndicesWithNumbers = Arrays.asList(0);

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndicesWithNumbers.contains(columnIndex))
                return Double.class;
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        }
    }
```

Here is a complete example to test yourself:

```
public class SorterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            DefaultTableModel dm = new CustomTableModel();
            dm.addColumn("Integers");
            dm.addColumn("Strings");
            //@formatter:off 
            Object[][] data = { 
                    { 1, "Something" }, { 102, "Something Else" }, 
                    { 55, "Something" }, { 66, "Something" },
                    { 1000, "Something" }, { 1524, "Something" }, 
                    { 5801, "Something" }, { -55, "Something" },};
            //@formatter:on
            for (Object[] row : data) {
                dm.addRow(row);
            }
            JTable table = new JTable(dm);
            table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
        });
    }

    public static class CustomTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
        private final List<Integer> columnIndicesWithNumbers = Arrays.asList(0);

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndicesWithNumbers.contains(columnIndex))
                return Double.class;
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Preview:**

[image: preview]

After your clarifications in the comment section:

You can `@Override` `getValueAt` method in order to return integers instead of strings.

Full example:

```
public class SorterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            DefaultTableModel dm = new CustomTableModel();
            dm.addColumn("Integers");
            dm.addColumn("Strings");
            //@formatter:off 
            Object[][] data = { 
                    { "1", "Something" }, { "102", "Something Else" }, 
                    { "55", "Something" }, { "66", "Something" },
                    { "1000", "Something" }, { "1524", "Something" }, 
                    { "5801", "Something" }, { "-55", "Something" },};
            //@formatter:on
            for (Object[] row : data) {
                dm.addRow(row);
            }
            JTable table = new JTable(dm);
            table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
        });
    }

    public static class CustomTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
        private final List<Integer> columnIndicesWithNumbers = Arrays.asList(0);

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            Object value = super.getValueAt(row, column);
            if (columnIndicesWithNumbers.contains(column)) {
                return Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(value));
            }
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndicesWithNumbers.contains(columnIndex))
                return Double.class;
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my code I'm setting the data as Strings. Following your example it would be something like:
`Object[][] data = {{ "1", "Something" }, { "102", "Something Else" }};`

Is it possible that its whats causing the problem? I dont really know if internally Swing casts all cells into Strings ( in that case, the problem would be something else).

Right now my code return the correct class for each column, but does it need the content of the cell to be casted into its class?

Edit: I forgot to say thank you very much for your time!!!!

Comment: @ÁngelDíazdeVivar Well, why don't you avoid setting data-integers as Strings? Use Integer.parseInt(string) and set the data as Integers.

Comment: Yep, it's something i would have definitely done for myself, but this is inherited code and its entirely based on that data being Strings.
If there is no other solution I'll have to rewrite a lot of code, that's why I'm looking for another solution

Comment: OMG I love you! I'm gonna try that

Comment: @ÁngelDíazdeVivar I am glad that I helped you. As I see you are relatively a new user, read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't cast the types doing that.
When defining the columns, you should instantiate the type of column before setting anything in.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer!! But I'm not sure if I understand what you are saying ^^'
Could you specify a bit more please?